# How to implement drag to select function as seen in Google Photos app

Tags: android, google-photos

[Seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydBjsZnHrwM&feature=youtu.be&t=50s)

In the Google Photos app, in the photos tab, you can long-click a picture to select. If you keep holding the screen you can drag to highlight additional pictures to perform an action upon. From a coding standpoint how can I implement this functionality in both a list and grid view. I haven't been able to find any sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You have severals libraries existing that do the heavy lifting for you.
I'm using : https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview

and it's working great.

Comment: I will try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Andros: It's not downloading dependency needed for that library . Any help ?